# Command Tilde in Finder, prevent focus on Desktop at end of cycle

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

Say I have 2 finder windows open, **A** and **B**.

I begin focussed on **A**, then `⌘ + ~` to focus on **B**, finally `⌘ + ~` once more, and it still leaves **B** in front, but **B** is now slightly grayed out (same style as finder window **A** when it's behind other finder windows).

This 3rd location is focussed on the **Desktop**, how do I prevent the Desktop from receiving focus on `⌘ + ~`? I only want actual Finder windows to receive focus?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I don't think the answer below solves the problem. I discovered your question after I'd asked mine: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383706/cycle-finder-windows-but-exclude-the-desktop

Answer (score 2):

### Change Finder App Cycle Window Behaviour

To prevent the Desktop from receiving focus on <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>, you will need to change the shortcut for Finder's menu option `Cycle Through Windows`.

1. Open `System Preferences`
2. Open the `Keyboard` setting
3. Select the `Shortcuts` menu button
4. Select the `App Shorcuts` from the list in the left window pane
5. Click the `+` button
6. For `Application:` option, select `Finder`
7. For `Menu Title:` enter `Cycle Through Windows`
8. For `Keyboard Shortcut:` perform <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> (or any you are comfortable)

### Check Keyboard Shortcut for Move Focus to Next Window

1. Open `System Preferences`
2. Open the `Keyboard` setting
3. Select the `Shortcuts` menu button
4. Select the `Keyboard` from the list in the left window pane
5. Check the keyboard shortcut for `Move focus to next window`
6. You may need to enable it, and you may need to change it to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

Note: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> will then be your <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> and will be for `Move focus to *previous* window` shortcut.

### Operating System

macOS (High Sierra)
v10.13.6

Answer (score 1):

It is selecting the Desktop, and any icons on it.